# PHP writeexcel and UTF-8 support

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

Has anyone of you ever used php_writeexcel (http://www.bettina-attack.de/jonny/view.php/projects/php_writeexcel/)?

I would like to know if there is an easy way to enable utf-8 support. php_writeexcel exports html to Microsoft Excel documents, yet it can't display certain characters:

http://pastebin.com/AgVpph7F

Perhaps I could solve this with some php functions?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's possible that your string is in some other encoding than UTF-8. Can you post the output of `bin2hex($string);`.

Comment: here it is: c497c48dc5a1c48dc4afc499c5a1c48dc5abc5b3c3bcc3b3

Comment: Well that seems to be valid. Sorry I can't really help with the Excel specific stuff.

Comment: have you tried http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: You should definitely try @FlakronBytyqi suggestion. It has everything you need to get export to excel files. If, on the other hand, you want to use this library, you would probably need to go into `class.writeexcel_worksheet.inc.php`, find the method `write()` and replace this line `$token = $_[2];` (784) with `$token = mb_convert_encoding($_[2], "UTF-8");`. I haven't tested this, but it may work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Php_writeexcel](http://www.bettina-attack.de/jonny/view.php/projects/php_writeexcel/) is a port of the Perl module [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/). However, the port is from a time when Unicode strings weren't supported in the underlying Excel file format.

Later (2.xx) versions of Spreadsheet::WriteExcel have native support for Unicode but they haven't been ported to PHP.

As such you won't be able to handle Unicode strings with php_writeexcel.

Answer (score 1):

For fields with special characters (eg french) I use utf8_decode() to get the special characters to show up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a perfect solution, but iconv will convert some of those characters.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Depending how you want the unsupported characters to be handled:

`iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//IGNORE','ėčščįęščūųüó');`

output: üó

`iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT','ėčščįęščūųüó');`

output: ??????????üó